VBA Code to create separate files from one list
I have this VBA Code:
Sub KundendatenExport()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim DestPath As String

    ' Set the destination path (you need to adjust this)
    DestPath = SpeicherOrt

    ' Set the worksheet containing the list
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Teststruktur")
    
    ' Set the range of the list
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    ' Loop through each cell in the range
    For Each c In rng
        ' Check if the row is empty
        If c.Value <> "" Then
            ' Check if column B value is "Ja"
            If ws.Cells(c.Row, "B").Value = "Ja" Then
                ' Create a new workbook
                Set wb = Workbooks.Add
                
                ' Copy the headers from the main list
                ws.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=wb.Sheets(1).Rows(1)
                
                ' Copy the current row
                ws.Range("A" & c.Row & ":AD" & c.Row).Copy Destination:=wb.Sheets(1).Rows(2)
                
                ' Save the new workbook with the client name and calendar week
                wb.SaveAs DestPath & c.Value & ws.Cells(c.Row, "D").Value & "KW" & Format(Now, "ww"), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
                wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
            End If
        Else
            Exit For ' Exit the loop if the row is empty
        End If
    Next c
End Sub

this generally works. But now i need the programm to only create one file for a customer if a specific value is found in row b then all data with the same name in row a should be put into the same file. If the specific value is not there then just create a new file
thanks
I just want this to work, i am very tired
Edit: Here is a Image of an example table
enter image description here

What is the specific value in the row? In what column? Will all the rows for a single company be grouped together or potentially separated? Can you reopen a file if you've already closed it?  You need to be more specific, and show how you've tried to modify the above code so we can help.


Assuming the custmer name is on Col A
Use Dictionary object to consolidate all data for each customer
ws.Cells(c.Row, "D").Value is removed from the file name

Microsoft documentation:

Range.Resize property (Excel)


Application.Union method (Excel)


Range.EntireRow property (Excel)

Option Explicit

Sub KundendatenExport()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim DestPath As String
    Dim objDic As Object, sKey
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Set the destination path (you need to adjust this)
    DestPath = "D:\temp\" ' for testing
'    DestPath = SpeicherOrt
    ' Set the worksheet containing the list
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) ' for testing
'    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Teststruktur")
    ' Set the range of the list
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Resize(, 2)
    Dim arrData: arrData = rng.Value
    ' Loop through each cell in the range
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrData)
        ' Check if the row is empty
        sKey = arrData(i, 1)
        If Len(sKey) > 0 Then
            If Not objDic.exists(sKey) Then
                Set objDic(sKey) = ws.Cells(1, "A")
            End If
            ' Check if column B value is "Ja"
            If arrData(i, 2) = "Ja" Then
                Set objDic(sKey) = Application.Union(objDic(sKey), ws.Cells(i + 1, "A"))
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each sKey In objDic.Keys
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add
        If objDic(sKey).Cells.Count > 1 Then
            objDic(sKey).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        End If
        wb.SaveAs DestPath & sKey & "KW" & Format(Now, "ww"), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub



This almost works perfectly, the only thing that is not working now is, that if Collum B is "Nein" then even if a customer name is multiple times in the list a new workbook needs to be created for each row.
So lets say if a customer name appears three times in the list and has the parameter "Nein" in collum B (Collum B is used to determine if a customer recives all orders in one file or one file per order) then for each row with that customer name a new file with the data has to be created, thats why i used the collum D data as a addition to the save name. Collum D is a unique identifiier.

Are all three cells in Col B marked with "Nein"? What's on Col D?
How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator

| Customer | Collectiv Customs | x   | Ident Number |
| -------- | ----------------- | --- | ------------ |
| A        | Ja                | N/A | 2342342354   |
| A        | Ja                | N/A | 23423423     |
| B        | Nein              | N/A | 645676       |
| C        | Nein              | N/A | 5677         |

Not a cells in Collum B are marked with "Nein", this depends on wether a customer has booked a special deal. Col D is just a Ident Number for the Order proccess, but this number is always unique even it is a order from a customer that is already in the list. I tried showing this in the table i created.
